# Any way to use object code in a User Control as a template for a new Object in a Sharepoint 2010 web part?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint

I'm trying to do something my teacher says can't be done; I would like to prove him wrong.

In the CreateChildControls method of my SharePoint 2010 webpart, I am referencing a User Control file called "ChartUserControl.ascx" in my project that contains the ASP.NET code for a WebChartControl object configured just the way I want it. WebChartControl has an ID of "OrderQtyChart".

What I want to do is take the code from that UserControl and use it create a new WebChartControl, called "chart", with matching configuration. I'm trying to do this because there are callbacks etc. that need to be performed on the chart after it's created to actually populate it with chart-stuff.

So, my code:

```
WebChartControl chart;

protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    ChartUserControl userControl = new ChartUserControl(); 
    // referencing file ChartUserControl.ascx as an object

    chart = userControl.FindControl("OrderQtyChart") as WebChartControl; 
    // or
    chart = (WebChartControl)userControl.FindControl("OrderQtyChart"); 

    // Trying to tell the code to create 'chart' using the code defined in object 
       "OrderQtyChart" located in ChartUserControl.ascx
}
```

Or something like that. In either instance above, 'chart' will return null.

I'm trying to use the front end code of OrderQtyChart as a template for 'chart'; they're both the same type of object  and I don't get any errors until I try to create 'chart' on my page, at which point I'm told it's null.

Is there a way to do this? It would save me a ton of time not to have to configure 'chart' completely at creation time. Even if I have to reference my front-end code for OrderQtyChart a different way.

Thanks.

[Edited 7/9 for clarity]

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do seems very well possible and I assume your teacher did not understand your question correctly. Here are a few tips on how this is done:

1. `Object A` could be one of these:

   1. A visual control such as label or textbox. In this case your will have to traverse the visual controls from parent to child by doing `direct parent.FindControl("ObjectA");`
   2. It is an instance of a class. This might be a `MyClass` or a new textbox that is created by  code. In this case you'll have to create a public property that has a getter which returns `ObjectA`. although you can use `FindControl` in case `ObjectA` is a UI component that is created and added dynamically at run-time. Otherwise, you'll have to stick with property.
2. `FindControl` will not traverse the parent to child hierarchy, so you'll have to do a recursive method in order to successfully find the `ObjectA` or if you have access to its direct parent, call `FindControl` on that. More info here: http://geekswithblogs.net/QuandaryPhase/archive/2009/05/06/asp.net-recursive-findcontrol-amp-extension-methods.aspx
3. Page life cycle plays an important role here, so make sure that you keep it in mind or you'll end up with a `null` reference that is not really caused by `FindControl`

Comment: Hi BenJ, thanks for the response.
Unfortunately, the code you suggest in point 2 is a no-go. I see that I shouldn't have been so general in my original post. I will edit it to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

Gah, never mind. I realized I can just call the user control directly and I'm seriously overcomplicating this.

That's a whole new question, so I'll just start a different thread.